# How can I read emails with attachments from gmail in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have mail box in Google Apps. I am trying to read the new mail's subject from and Toaddress everything and to download the attachments from the gmail account in vb.net. I tried using https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom but i cannot read all the mails as well as the attachments.

Can we use the python imaplib dll in vb.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I download all emails with attachments from Gmail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348630/how-can-i-download-all-emails-with-attachments-from-gmail)

Comment: @Tim S. van Haren: same issue, but can you translate it into VB.Net?

Comment: can you send me the code to use the imaplib dll in vb.net

Comment: Here's a C# version of an IMAP client that you can use: http://interimap.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[This is an article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MimeClient.aspx) where you can find a lot of usefull information how to send and read email using pop3email client within attachment and without, including gmail. I hope example in c# wouldn't be great obstacle for you.