# How to download attachment from gmail using python?

Tags: python, django

How to download the attachment from gmail inbox using python program?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348630/how-can-i-download-all-emails-with-attachments-from-gmail/642988#642988

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [poplib](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html) in general.

And there is python-gmail library: [libgmail](http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @DrTyrsa actually i don't know how to login and what procedure is to be used to fetch latest mail and then i have to download the attached file.

Comment: @Madhur Rampal Have you clicked the links I provided? libgmail has nice documentation. To login you should use `login()` method of the `libgmail.GmailAccount` class.