# Download a specific email from Gmail using Python

Tags: python, gmail, imap

Can someone help me customize an existing code sample?

I can see from the following article how to connect to gmail and download content, but I can't figure out how to search for a specific email and only download the timestamp and body?

ARTICLE: [How can I download all emails with attachments from Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348630/how-can-i-download-all-emails-with-attachments-from-gmail)

I specifically want to grab the emails from "Alerts@foobank.com" for the last 5 days and download the send time and body of the emails.  I'll then parse this to determine which emails I need to use.

I'm self-taught and am having a hard time customizing the script above to do this.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

JD

Comment: Which [search criterias](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap-search-critera.asp) have you tried so far?

Comment: It is not Gmail related but IMAP/POP I bet, so you should search for that - except you are selfkiller and are doing it with webclient ;p

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest using [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) as it papers over many of the more esoteric aspects of IMAP.

The following snippet will pull messages based on your criteria, parse the message strings to [`email.message.Message`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message) instances and print the `Date` and `From` headers.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import email
from imapclient import IMAPClient

HOST = 'imap.gmail.com'
USERNAME = 'username'
PASSWORD = 'password'
ssl = True

today = datetime.today()
cutoff = today - timedelta(days=5)

## Connect, login and select the INBOX
server = IMAPClient(HOST, use_uid=True, ssl=ssl)
server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
select_info = server.select_folder('INBOX')

## Search for relevant messages
## see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.5
messages = server.search(
    ['FROM "Alerts@foobank.com"', 'SINCE %s' % cutoff.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')])
response = server.fetch(messages, ['RFC822'])

for msgid, data in response.iteritems():
    msg_string = data['RFC822']
    msg = email.message_from_string(msg_string)
    print 'ID %d: From: %s Date: %s' % (msgid, msg['From'], msg['date'])
```

Comment: Thanks Rob!  I just ported this over from Python2.6 to 2.7 and I now get the following error when calling message_from_string... 'UnicodeEncodeError: ascii codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3041: ordinal not in range(128)'.  Do I have to performs some sort of transformation on the msg_String?  And I'm reading in the same email, so the email payload cannot be the issue.

Comment: Did you upgrade IMAPClient to 0.10 or greater? Behaviour changed in that release; Functions now return unicode objects (see https://bitbucket.org/mjs0/imapclient/src/tip/NEWS.rst). The particular issue in this case is a non-breaking space. You can remove it safely (probably) with .replace(u'\xa0', u'')

Comment: The `server.search` line above didn't work for me in imapclient 2.0, I had to update the syntax as follows:
`messages = server.search(['FROM', "Alerts@foobank.com", 'SINCE', cutoff.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')])`

Answer (score 3):

```
import imaplib
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
obj.login('username','password')
obj.select()

today = datetime.today()
cutoff = today - timedelta(days=5)
dt = cutoff.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
typ, data = obj.search(None, '(SINCE %s) (FROM "Alerts@foobank.com")'%(dt,))
print data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime as dt
from imap_tools import MailBox, Q
date = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=5)
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(Q(from_='Alerts@foobank.com', date_gte=date)):
        sent_time = msg.date
        body = msg.text or msg.html
        for att in msg.attachments:
            att.filename         # str: 'cat.jpg'
            att.content_type     # str: 'image/jpeg'
            att.payload          # bytes: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\'
```

*Note that there is no imap search criteria "with attachments"

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools