# Read MIME Message stored in text file with Python

Tags: python, mime

I have a MIME Message stored in a 'text/plain' file that looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/sPWWC9LL

The MIME Message is supposed to be a multipart message.

How do I parse this in Python? I have tried email.message_from_string(), but it's still encoded as 'text/plain', and thus I can't use the email library to parse it.

My code looks like this:

```
f = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/raw.txt', 'r')
msg = email.message_from_string(f.read())
i = 1

for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue

    ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(part.get_content_type())
    filename = 'part-%03d%s' % (i, ext)

    fp = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + filename, 'wb')
    fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
    fp.close()
    i += 1
```

I would be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to parse the message and walk through the parts using code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348630/how-can-i-download-all-emails-with-attachments-from-gmail/642988#642988), however, first you'll need to add

```
Content-type: multipart/alternative;  
    boundary="cbsms-main-boundary"
```

to the beginning of the message, or preserve the full original message.

---

I believe your code works. After adding the two lines above to [MIME_Message_in_text_file.txt](http://pastebin.com/sPWWC9LL), I ran

test.py:

```
import os
import sys
import mimetypes
import email

msg = email.message_from_file(open(sys.argv[1]))

for i,part in enumerate(msg.walk(),1):
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
        continue
    ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(part.get_content_type())
    filename='part-%03d%s'%(i, ext)
    # filename=os.path.join('settings.MEDIA_ROOT', filename)
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
```

this way:

```
% test.py MIME_Message_in_text_file.txt
```

and received:

```
part-002.xml
part-004.jpe
part-005.ksh
```

Comment: @Oscar: I made a mistake in my first response. Change `boundary="--cbsms-main-boundary"` --> `boundary="cbsms-main-boundary"
`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: Is it possible to set the Content-type and boundary without modifying the file? I've tried to do this:

msg = email.message_from_string(f.read())
msg.set_type('multipart/alternative')
msg.set_boundary('cbsms-main-boundary')

But it doesn't work

Comment: @Oscar: Sure. Just define a string `extra='''Content-type...'''` and then use `msg = email.message_from_string(extra+f.read())`.