# How to get csv attachment from email and save it

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, email-attachments, imaplib

I am trying to get the attachment from an email and save it to a specific folder with the original file name. The email is very basic and does not have much to it other than the attachment. The file is a csv file and there will be only one per email. This is what I have so far, but I'm new to this and am not sure how to proceed. This is using Outlook if that helps. Any help is appreciated.

```
import imaplib
import email


mail=imaplib.IMAP4('mailserver.com')
mail.login("username", "password")
mail.select("DetReport")

typ, msgs = mail.uid('Search', None, '(SUBJECT "Detection")')
msgs = msgs[0].split()

for emailid in msgs:
    resp, data = mail.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1] 
    m = email.message_from_string(email_body)


    message=m.get_content_maintype()
```

FYI, when I run the `message=m.get_content_maintype()` it says it is text.

Answer (score 16):

I looked around some more and tried a few more things. These: 
[Downloading multiple attachments using imaplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225763/downloading-multiple-attachments-using-imaplib)
and [How do I download only unread attachments from a specific gmail label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182499/how-do-i-download-only-unread-attachments-from-a-specific-gmail-label) had the answer once I played with it a little bit.

Code that worked:

```
import imaplib
import email
import os

svdir = 'c:/downloads'


mail=imaplib.IMAP4('mailserver')
mail.login("username","password")
mail.select("DetReport")

typ, msgs = mail.search(None, '(SUBJECT "Detection")')
msgs = msgs[0].split()

for emailid in msgs:
    resp, data = mail.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1] 
    m = email.message_from_string(email_body)


    if m.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
    continue

    for part in m.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        filename=part.get_filename()
        if filename is not None:
            sv_path = os.path.join(svdir, filename)
            if not os.path.isfile(sv_path):
                print sv_path       
                fp = open(sv_path, 'wb')
                fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                fp.close()
```

POP3:

```
import poplib
import email

server = poplib.POP3(pop_server)
server.user(user)
server.pass_(pass)

# get amount of new mails and get the emails for them
messages = [server.retr(n+1) for n in range(len(server.list()[1]))]

# for every message get the second item (the message itself) and convert it to a string with \n; then create python email with the strings
emails = [email.message_from_string('\n'.join(message[1])) for message in messages]

for mail in emails:
    # check for attachment;
    for part in mail.walk():
        if not mail.is_multipart():
            continue
        if mail.get('Content-Disposition'):
            continue
        file_name = part.get_filename()
        # check if email park has filename --> attachment part
        if file_name:
            file = open(file_name,'w+')
            file.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            file.close()
```