# How can get the email success login status?

Tags: python, email, authentication, pop3

I am trying to input my both account and password to the system and then wanna return the status of email login, True for success login. Now I am using poplib to login the account and return the email stat. Are there any method to return the login status by poplib at the same time (Or not by poplib)? Thanks.

```
import poplib
server = poplib.POP3(pop3_server)
print(server.getwelcome())
server.user(email)
server.pass_(password)
print('Messages: %s. Size: %s' % server.stat())
server.quit()
```

Comment: take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669202/get-emails-with-python-and-poplib

Comment: @JibinMathews Thanks, I know how to connect server and also the status for success now. However, if the email is wrong, I have no idea how to throw the error as shown below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
import poplib
server = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.googlemail.com', '995')
print(server.getwelcome())
server.user(email)
try:
   status = server.pass_(pass)
   print('Messages: %s. Size: %s' % server.stat())
except Exception as error:
   status = "Not OK"
   print(error)

if "+OK" in status:
    print ("Login Successful!!") # Return True
else:
    print ("Login Failed!!") # Return False

server.quit()
```

Output in case of Error:

```
+OK Gpop ready for requests from 114.143.178.34 c14mb53749528ybi
-ERR [AUTH] Username and password not accepted.
Login Failed!!
```

*Hope this answers your question!!*

Comment: Thanks , however when I tried to login a wrong email account, it cannot throw the error and stopped program. I also try to throw it like "except poplib.error_proto", but its not working.

Comment: The error is shown as below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_user_login_info.py", line 32, in <module>
    check_mail(email, password, pop3_server)
  File "check_user_login_info.py", line 13, in check_mail
    except poplib.error_proto('-ERR EOF'):
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Comment: Why do you want to throw an error when login fails. At failure, it will go into `except `block and eventually print `Login Failed`. However I have edited my solution to print error

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt work for me. First, when I add the line "status = server.pass_(p)", the program just keep loading and I have to stop it manually. Besides, when change the line back to "server.pass_(p)" and login with wrong password, the error is detected, but it doesnt go to the except block and simply stopped the program. I have no idea why it happen.

Comment: Are you using the whole code in my solution or do u have made any changes

Comment: Yea exactly. But just now, I change a bit your code and move the if - statement before the server.quit(). It works now. Thanks a lot.