# Get all information about an email

Tags: python, encoding, imap

I want to get all my emails with all their information, e.g. Body, Subject, Date Received, Folders, Attachments, From, To, etc.

I found this:
[How can I download all emails with attachments from Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348630/how-can-i-download-all-emails-with-attachments-from-gmail)

But it's only subjects/from/attachments.

I copied pretty much everything and added this:

```
for payload in mail.get_payload():
        print part.get_payload(decode=True)
```

But I'm getting `(�� (�� (��` at times and html at times.
I just want to have simple access to an email message where everything is decoded, easily handleable.

Comment: impala does not give you everything nicely decodable, easily `handable`.  It is a low level library, and needs to be combined with MIME parsers and knowledge of various specifications.  `IMAP` and email is *not* simple.

Comment: @Max I actually thought twice when I wrote that word. "That sounds a little off." But I still submitted it.

Comment: It's ok, my autocorrect changed imaplib to impala :)