# How to filter the mails which contains attachment in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Can any help me out to code the java program that filters only the mails which contains attachments?

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348630/how-can-i-download-all-emails-with-attachments-from-gmail

Comment: Hi,thanks for response,actually I want to know SearchTerm  that filters only the mails with attachment.Is there any such kind of class  like FromTerm,BodyTerm,etc..!!

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, it's not simple to tell whether a message has attachments.  You'll find more information in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#hasattach).  You can search for messages with a Content-Type header containing "multipart", but then you'll need to look at each of those messages more closely to determine whether any of them really does have attachments.  You have to decide whether you only want to handle simple cases or more complex cases as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bill Shannon for your prompt response,actually even for some text mails also we are getting Content-Type with 'multipart', that's why I got the question i.e can we find whether the attachment is there or not ,with out going through all bodyparts? .Any ways thanks again.

Comment: MIME allows a multipart message to have only a single text body part, and some poor quality mailers will just always create multipart messages, that's just one of the reasons why it's difficult to tell if a message has attachments or not.