# Hushmail: Download all emails when POP & IMAP is disabled (USER/PASS included)

Tags: php, python, email, imap, mechanize

I want to back up my emails from a non-premium account I have with [Hushmail](http://hushmail.com), so I can delete the account. Initially tried to use Thunderbird, however, POP & IMAP is a "[premium](https://help.hushmail.com/entries/20348693-Thunderbird-IMAP-)" feature. Thought I could modify the code from a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348630/how-can-i-download-all-emails-with-attachments-from-gmail/642988?s=2%7C0.1564#642988), but still requires IMAP. I thought then that perhaps I could use something to gather the content loop-wise from the "show all headers" URL for each individual email without using IMAP. The layout is like this:

```
https://www.hushmail.com/preview/hushmail/<<<USERNAME>>>@hush.ai/rawmessage/Inbox/<<<EMAIL NUMBER>>>?raw=1
```

Here `<<<USERNAME>>>` is the username, *i.e.* [local-part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address), and `<<<EMAIL NUMBER>>>` is the number of the email. I have the first and last numbers, call them `first` and `last`, say. The above link, once I'm logged in to my Hushmail account through the browser, can be used to gather all emails, however, there are gaps in the `<<<EMAIL NUMBER>>>`'s, like 100, 102, 216, so a call to

```
https://www.hushmail.com/preview/hushmail/<<<USERNAME>>>@hush.ai/rawmessage/Inbox/101?raw=1
                                                                      EMAIL NUMBER^^^
```

would return a page with the message "An unexpected error has occurred", which could be used to our advantage.

---

> Created an account for your own testing:
>
> USER: so36756464@hush.ai
>
> PASS: 510526A5A139B330BFE078D907FA5BB21ABF9C960E4B857180F4EBA460337969

Comment: So, run curl in a loop?

Comment: @Max, I tried that, and the source contains nothing that's in the email.

Answer (score 1):

Try using WATIR-WEBDRIVER (ruby)

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

    b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    b.goto 'https://www.hushmail.com/preview/hushmail/'

    b.text_field(:name => 'hush_username').set ‘me@hushmail.com’
    b.text_field(:name => 'hush_passphrase').set ‘me_password’
    b.button(:value => 'Sign in').click
    $i = 0  

    while $i <= 5000 do
            sleep 1.5
            b.goto 'https://www.hushmail.com/preview/hushmail/me@hushmail.com/rawmessage/Inbox/' + $i.to_s + '?raw=1'
            if (b.html =~ /eml file/)
                    File.open('hushmail_' + $i.to_s, 'w') do |f|
                            f.puts b.html
                    end
            end
            $i += 1
    end
```