# Create a Generator to read email and process messages

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, generator

I am trying to write some code to read my inbox and process some attachments if present.  I decided this would be a good time to learn how generators work as I want to process all messages that have a particular subject.  I have gotten to the point where I can get all the attachments and relevant subjects but I sort of had to fake it as the iterator in the `for i in range . . .` was not advancing so I am advancing the `latest_email_id` in the loop

```
def read_email_from_gmail():
    try:
        print 'got here'
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
        mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
        mail.select('inbox')

        type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
        mail_ids = data[0]

        id_list = mail_ids.split()   
        first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
        latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])
        print latest_email_id


        while True:
            for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id - 1, -1):
                latest_email_id -= 1
                #do stuff to get attachment and subject
                yield attachment_data, subject


    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

for attachment, subject in read_email_from_gmail():
    x = process_attachment(attachment)
    y = process_subject(subject)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to advance through my in-box using a generator to hold state in the in-box?

Comment: You might want to compare your code to [e-satis'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/642988/190597). He shows a different way to iterate through the messages without the `for i in range(...)` loop.

Comment: I started with that approach and then wondered about a generator so I could encapsulate the code better - the other stuff I have to do to each email message is very extensive and like I said I am idly wondering how to use generators

Answer (score 0):

I have learned a bit more about generators and played around with the code I started with so I have a function that uses a generator to send each relevant email message subject to the main function.  This is what I have so far, and it works great for my needs

```
import imaplib
import email
FROM_EMAIL  = 'myemail@gmail.com'
FROM_PWD    = "mygmail_password"
SMTP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT   = 993
STOP_MESSAGES = set(['Could not connect to mailbox',
                     'No Messages or None Retrieved Successfully',
                     'Could not retrieve some message',
                     'Finished processing'])

def  read_emails():
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER)
    mail.login(FROM_EMAIL,FROM_PWD)
    mail.select('inbox')
    con_status, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
    if con_status != 'OK':
        yield 'Could not connect to mailbox'
    try:
        mail_ids = data[0].split()
    except Exception:
        yield 'No Messages or None Retrieved Successfully'
    print mail_ids

    processed = []
    while True:
        for mail_id in mail_ids:
            status, mdata = mail.uid('fetch', mail_id, '(RFC822)')
            if status != 'OK':
                yield 'Could not retrieve some message'
            if mail_id in processed:
                yield 'Finished processing'
            raw_msg = mdata[0][1]
            structured_msg = email.message_from_string(raw_msg)
            msg_subject = structured_msg['subject']
            processed.append(mail_id)
            yield msg_subject
```

To access my messages one by one, I then use the following block to get my messages

```
for msg_subj in read_emails():
    if msg_subj not in STOP_MESSAGES:
         do some stuff here with msg_subj
    else:
        print msg_subj
        break
```

I am accessing these messages by their `uid` as I will be deleting them later and would like to use the `uid` as the key to manage deletion.  For me the trick was to collect the `uid` in the list named `processed` and then check to see if I was going to circle through them again because I was working with a `uid` that had already been processed.