# Is it possible to get all emails from an inbox in GMail?

Tags: php, email, curl, gmail

Is it possible to get all of my emails from your GMail inbox rather than only unread email? My current PHP script only gets unread email but I want the whole inbox.

I am making use of PHP and CURL. Firstly, is it possible to do this?

If so, can someone give me some hints on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an IMAP API.

See: [Fetching attachments from gmail via either python or php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312284/fetching-attachments-from-gmail-via-either-python-or-php)

Answer (score 0):

you might also check out ryan grove's larch project:

http://wonko.com/post/larch-syncs-messages-from-one-imap-server-to-another

it's made to sync imap accounts, but will give you an idea of how to use imap with ruby. (similar in other languages.)